# passing in args to a Closure for a StreamingMarkupBuilder

Tags: groovy, markupbuilder, streamingmarkupbuilder

Groovy 2.4, Spring 5.3.13

Not having much luck using `StreamingMarkupBuilder` to create some XML, serialize it and print it

```
public void createMsgToStreamOut( String strCreatedAt, String strEntity, String strIdNum, String strEvent) {
    def streamBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder();
    streamBuilder.encoding = "UTF-8"
    def xml = streamBuilder.bind{ strCreatedAt, strEntity, strIdNum, strEvent -> 
        >> some magic goes here
    }
    def xmlStr = XmlUtil.serialize( xml)
    println xmlStr;
}

createMsgToStreamOut( "2022-09-10T12:13:14.567", "Matter", "907856", "create");
```

should give

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
  <timestamp>2022-09-10T12:13:14.567</timestamp>
  <entity>Matter</entity>
  <number>907856</number>
  <event>create</event>
</message>
```

next step is to stream the output to a Kafka producer.

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic you're looking for looks like that, I suppose:

```
def xml = streamBuilder.bind {
    message {
        timestamp(strCreatedAt)
        entity(strEntity)
        number(strIdNum)
        event(strEvent)
    }
}
```

Here is the fully working script:

```
import groovy.xml.*

createMsgToStreamOut( "2022-09-10T12:13:14.567", "Matter", "907856", "create");

void createMsgToStreamOut(String strCreatedAt, String strEntity, String strIdNum, String strEvent) {
    def streamBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder();
    streamBuilder.encoding = "UTF-8"
    def xml = streamBuilder.bind {
        message {
            timestamp(strCreatedAt)
            entity(strEntity)
            number(strIdNum)
            event(strEvent)
        }
    }
    def xmlStr = XmlUtil.serialize( xml)
    println xmlStr;
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: that did the trick, Thank You!